# Dynamically change layout and content of website depending on PHP Session variable

Tags: php, html, css, json, dynamic-content

I am receiving a list of available products and subproducts from a Java webservice and storing it in a session variable.

The products are presented on multiple pages and depending on the availability, some of the main products and their components have to be greyed out (background colors, text color, images changed etc.). In a further usecase they would be completely hidden.

It is an already existing website using php and javascript (no frameworks and cms).

What would be a clean way of altering the content based on the session variable?

Comment: Altering the existing PHP would be clean. Don't expect anyone to write this for you.

Comment: You can store the product and its availability in separate session variables and while loading the page check the session variables for the availability to decide the style for that product.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking... but could do something like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['available'])){
echo "<div>Item</div>";
} else if(isset($_SESSION['unavailable'])) {
echo "<div style='visibility:hidden;'>Item</div>";
}
```